# Decompress bytes using DeflateStream

Tags: c#, zlib, unzip, deflatestream

I'm trying to decompress a byte array. Because I want to extract a .png file from a zip.

I tried this:

```
var compressedData = ZlibStream.UncompressBuffer(cByteArray);

var uncompressedData = ZlibStream.CompressBuffer(compressedData);   

using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"F:\picture.png", FileMode.Create)){

fs.Write(uncompressedData, 0, uncompressedData);
}
```

But got the following error:
Bad state (unknown compression method (0x5C))

So can anyone help me out on how to get the file from the data.
The compressed data is from a zip file entry. So the header is excluded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DeflateStream`, not `ZlibStream`.  The former processes raw deflate data as wrapped in zip files.  The latter processes zlib streams, which is deflate data with a zlib wrapper.

Comment: I tried with System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream but I keep getting this error: "Found invalid data while decoding."

Comment: Then you did not extract the deflate data correctly from the zip file.  You could consider using the `ZipArchive` class instead, which will handle that for you.

Comment: It works great now! Turned out I had the layout wrong I read the extralength after compressed data instead of in front. Thanks